# how to pass parameter to the route php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Heres the code for the route:

```
<?php

use app\controllers\Home;
use app\core\App;
$app = new App();

$app->router->get('/', function(){
 echo "hello there";
});
$app->router->get('user/', 'user');
$app->router->get('/contact',  [Home::class,'contacts']);
$app->router->post('/contact', function(){
    echo "handlecontact";
   });
$app->run();
```

Heres the code for the router core class:

```
<?php
namespace app\core;
class router{
    public Request $request;
    public Response $response;
  protected array $routes = [];
  public function __construct(Request $request,Response $response)
  {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->response = $response;
  }
  public function get($path, $callback){
    $this->routes['get'][$path] = $callback;
  }
  public function post($path, $callback){
    $this->routes['post'][$path] = $callback;
  }
  public function resolve(){
    $path = $this->request->getpath();
    $method = $this->request->getmethod();
    $callback = $this->routes[$method][$path] ?? false;
    if($callback == false){
        $this->response->setstatuscode(404);
        return "not found";
    } 
    if(is_array($callback)){
        $callback[0] = new $callback[0]();
    }
    return call_user_func($callback,$this->request); 
  }
```

I want to be able to declare a route and pass a parameter to it. If i do it so like that it tells me route not found.
Like i want to be able to write the route like this:

```
$app->router->get('/contact/{id}', function(){
    echo $id; // to echo it out like this from the controller
   });
```

Can someone be of good help or also add something to the idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where you're stuck. We're glad to help sort issues out, but not to write your code for you (which a proper answer here would require us to.)

Comment: Defining a route in your PHP system is one thing - but you also need to make the web server pass this request on to PHP in the first place. Have you actually done anything in that regard ...?

Comment: yes i have done that already. i checked all the routes that was defined and it works just fine. But all i need is a way i can be able to pass a parameter at the end of the route, so that i can be able to grab it from the controller. Just like the way is done in laravel framework